# Custom authentication handler when using MapHttpAttributeRoutes in Web API 2

Tags: vb.net, routes, asp.net-web-api2

In a Web API 2 web service I currently have a custom authentication handler set up for the default route in `WebApiConfig.vb`, the default route looks like this:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name:="DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional},
      constraints:=Nothing,
      handler:=New AuthenticationHandler() With {.InnerHandler = New Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher(config)}
  )
```

And the AuthenticationHandler class looks like this:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Runtime.Caching
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class AuthenticationHandler
   Inherits DelegatingHandler

   Protected Overrides Function SendAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken As Threading.CancellationToken) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
      Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage
      Dim lblnIsAuthenticated As Boolean = False
      Dim tsc As New TaskCompletionSource(Of HttpResponseMessage)

        '// Do the authentication work here...


        if not lblnIsAuthenticated then
         '// Set the response
         response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
         response.Headers.Add("Status-Message", "Authentication failed.")
         tsc.SetResult(response)
         Return tsc.Task
        end if

      Return MyBase.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
   End Function
```

When I upgraded this service to Web API 2 I wanted to take advantage of http attribute routing, so I added `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` to `WebApiConfig.vb` and set up some of the controllers to use the `Route` and `RoutePrefix` attributes.  The problem is that this routing method doesn't take advantage of the custom authentication handler.  Is there any way to implement this same authentication handler for the http attribute routing?  I've searched around for a solution to this but don't see how to make this work.  Or do I need to just do standard routes?

UPDATE --
I also have some other routes in `WebApiConfig.vb` that have a different authentication handler on them so I don't think I can apply one handler globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add your handler to GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers; unless I'm mistaken the handlers added there are always invoked for all the requests. Unless you're trying to do something different?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, although I didn't mention in my original post that I have a couple other routes with a different handler on them.  I'm guessing if I add this to the global config it will apply to all routes?

Comment: Yes, it would apply to all requests. The way I usually deal with routes that need different handling is with custom attributes on the actions - for example, AllowAnonymous for actions that don't need authentication, then the handler knows it doesn't need to do anything by inspecting the attributes.

Comment: Or, if possible, look at using filters instead of handlers - that way you can apply them to the action or controller or global level and have as much control as you want.

Comment: Do you have an example of Filters that you can point me to, I'm not familiar with using those?

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters should give you the basics...

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info.  I used that reference as a basis and built a filter that worked for me. I didn't use the 401 challenge because I'm not doing Basic authentication, and I modified the filter code itself, but it's working for me now!